# Modify AdminCount to zero

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have found plenty of ways to modify the admincount value with PowerShell to a null value using clear but I want to keep track of it and change it from 1 to 0.

Looking for a solution to modify that property on a AD account.

```
Get-ADUser [user name] | Set-ADObject -Clear adminCount
```

Comment: So, you only want to change it to zero if it is _exactly 1_ or...?

Comment: Don't use `-Clear` if that's not the action you want.

Comment: Have you looked at MS's reference article which links to some VB script? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/ee361593(v=msdn.10)

Comment: I would probably read in the value on the user, write it out to a CSV (and store it in a variable) then via an if statement, flip the bit via 'Set-ADObject -Replace'

Comment: yes I would put in a if = 1 change to 0.  So I already know all the accounts that are = to 1 and that are not a member of a protected group so my goal is to take these users objects and run them through a script that will set it to 0 and mark the inherited security right.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer but only issue is that it will only change the value if it contains a value like 1.  If you used the clear function and it is now NULL then you can't use this command.  At least this is what I'm finding in my test.

```
Set-Aduser -Identity XXXX -Replace @{adminCount=0}
```